# Rewriting Optional without using isPresent

Tags: java, option-type

```
void spendTheNight() {
    Optional<Homework> homework = getHomeworkDueTonight();
    if (homework.isPresent()) {
        rushThrough(homework.get());
    } else {
        homework = getHomeworkDueNextWeek();
        if (homework.isPresent()) {
            workSlowlyOn(homework.get());
        } else {
            partyHard();
        }
    }
    goToBed();
}
```

I know it's bad practice to do `if..else` with `isPresent`; how can I rewrite this to make better use of `Optional` such that the flow of logic stays the same?

I was thinking of using `or`, `orElse`, or `orElseGet`, but not sure how to use them here, with that additional assignment in the first `else`.

(assume the custom methods can't be modified and must be used as-is)

Comment: You *think* it's bad practice why?

Comment: @user207421 so you're saying the above code is acceptable / not bad?

Comment: it defeats the point of using an `Optional` because you might as well be checking if the value wrapped inside `== null`

Comment: now answer my question :)

Comment: So don't use an `Optional`, or make better use of its API if it bugs you. But don't get sucked into the delusion of 'best practice'. There is no such thing.

Comment: I think that in your case you can't talk about bad practice. Naman's response is an alternative but it does pretty much the same thing that you've wrote in a more classical way. The main purpose of Optional here is to make sure that `getHomeworkDueTonight()` respects a contract. The contract is that when you call this method, it returns an `Optional`. The Optional forces you to check if there's a homework or not. With the `Homework` or `null` alternative, it's not obvious that this method could return null when there's no homework --> main reason of NPE when working with a team.

Comment: It may be a matter of taste, but I much prefer @Naman’s code over that in the question (and agree that it would make a fine answer to the question). I think of `isPresent()` and `get()` as low level and avoid them where I can (which is usually possible).

Comment: @Imaguest thank you for the giving me a new perspective on the way to go about thinking it!

Comment: @OleV.V. i agree as well that `isPresent` and `get` are pretty low level, and that `Optional` could (should?) be made use of by chaining methods, hence the question

Comment: If there is any such thing as 'best practice' in an engineering discipline, it is the least cost viable solution, which in this case would be the one you started with. There is no saving or other advantage in any other technique, pretty as they may be, and much as you may use them next time. You've already wasted more time on this than I would care to see any employee of mine consume on this trivia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the listed APIs by you `or`, `orElse`, or `orElseGet` return one or the other value, your code seems to be more around running a stub based on some conditions around return types of the methods.

You can use `ifPresentOrElse` in such a case, since Java 9:

```
Optional<Homework> homework = getHomeworkDueTonight(); 
homework.ifPresentOrElse(this::rushThrough, () -> { 
    Optional<Homework> hw = getHomeworkDueNextWeek(); 
    hw.ifPresentOrElse(this::workSlowlyOn, this::partyHard); 
});
goToBed();
```